# Can't enable nginx gzip on Elastic Beanstalk (Php, symfony)

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, nginx, http-compression

I'm facing an issue with AWS Elastic Beanstalk(Php,Symfony) and gzip.

I'm trying to enable Gzip compression but it work only for .svg files with this configuration :

[Folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZK0.png)

nginx.config

```
server {
gzip on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
gzip_min_length 1400;
}
```

symfony.config

```
location / {



try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
gzip_min_length 1400;



if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
   return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

 if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }
}



location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;


}
```

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the nginx settings with `nginx.conf`? If yes, then the file should be `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Yes, i just tried it but i received this error : 
"server" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get this error because your server block is not nested inside an http block. What you could do is take the original /etc/nginx/nginx.conf from your instance and add it to your .platform/nginx/nginx.conf with the required modifications in regards to gzip config.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Marcin and Julien B it work now.

I changed the nginx directory to .platform/nginx/nginx.conf and get a default nginx config from the beanstalk instance, and set myconfig on it.

nginx.conf

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65235;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {


        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        #gzip                  off;
        #gzip_comp_level       4;
        #gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        gzip on;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-otf application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/xml application/json font/opentype font/otf font/ttf image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/html text/javascript text/plain text/xml;
        gzip_min_length 1400;


        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }

}
```